# Updating date column with sysdate throwing Uniuqe constraint voilation in oracle. Happening randomly as Date is Primary key

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle

I have two sqls file which includes more that 300000 records each. The issue is there are some duplicate records which are getting update
which causing unique constraint violation issue. Please find example below

Planid + Last_mod_Date  is Composite Primary Key in PLAN_HISTORY table. There is PLAN_HISTORY table present where records gets inserted by using PLAN_HISTORY_TRIGGER whenever PLAN table gets update. which is causing this issue randomly whenever sysdate is same.

Example :

```
File 1: 

UPDATE plan SET enroll_id = '1', Last_mod_Dt = sysdate where plan_id = '1234';

File 2 : 

UPDATE plan SET plan_name = 'TPA', Last_mod_Dt = sysdate where plan_id = '1234';
```

As there are many records and which may get duplicate for PLAN_ID+SYSDATE(last_mod_dt). how i can avoid this issue ?

I have think of some solutions like

1. ADD seconds to sysdate but again it will throw same exception as some point of time date will same.
2. I can add some delay in between two files but not sure how much this is possible in oracle
3. last option is i need to find all duplicate plan ids from two files and put them into single update statement.

But is there any good solutions for prob like theses ?

Comment: How do you fix this issue?  Don't use a date column in a primary key.  I would recommend some sort of auto-incremented integer instead.

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> Planid + Last_mod_Date is Primary Key in PLAN table. There is PLAN_HISTORY table present which gets update by using PLAN_HISTORY_TRIGGER whenever plan table gets update. which is causing this issue randomly whenever sysdate is same.

Take last_mod_date out of the primary key; your main table should have only one record for a plan_id (the latest one). The primary key for PLAN should be: plan_id

Have your trigger **insert** (you said update; no, it should be an insert) the old row values from PLAN into the PLAN_HISTORY table at the time the update is done. **The history table shouldn't have a primary key**, just a nonunique index on plan id. The history table might also benefit from a date column that says when the old values became invalidated (updated)

The queries you posted don't immediately seem that they would cause this issue, unless you're putting more than one plan ID 1234 in your plan table. I don't think you're doing this because you don't put the last_mod_date in the where clause, and it is a massive problem to have a composite primary key on a table but then not specify one of its columns in the where clause. I think your problem is that you've put a primary key on the history table so firing two updates quick enough that the trigger makes inserts to the history table before sysdate changes, causes a PK violation.

Comment: Thanks Caius for correcting me . yes you are right PLAN_HISTORY trigger inserts the records in PLAN_HISTORY table where composite key  present causing the issue PLAN_ID+LAST_MOD_DT.


its 5 years old table structure and i cant modify table for this issue .

Comment: I'd assert that you can; what is going to stop working if you remove the primary  key from the history table and replace it with a non unique index? This is a bug, it needs fixing, it doesn't matter how old it is